# G213 G-key and Fkey same time

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

i play a game tha use F-keys , how i can run Script without lose the F-key
example:
I use F12 key for skill, but if assing Script to G-12 i cant use F12 in game it will run the script.
Thanks

Comment: A script is independent from a binding on the same key.  So, both the script and the binding are working simultaneously.  So, I don't understand your problem.  Please show your script.

Comment: `assing Script to G-12`  - You cannot assign script to G12.  You can only assign a macro.  Script is written on Lua and handles `G_PRESSED` event.